# 1x Specific Chain

Tags: chain

I was shopping around and noticed the presence of [1x specific chains](http://www.jensonusa.com/Chains/SRAM-PC-X1-11-Speed-Chain) for the specific cassette size (9, 10, 11).  Is there actually something special about these changes or is this just marketing?

```
1X specific chain designed with SRAM's XX1 geometry
```

Comment: Well, speed specific chains for the rear aren't new. They're necessary due to cassette spacings. But, I only see SRAM selling 1x11 and 1x12 specific chains (and they don't do a 2x12 or whatever, it seems).

Comment: There is nothing of substance on that linked page to indicate that is fundamentally anything besides an 11 speed chain.

Comment: @Batman: 12sp is only present with SRAM Eagle (1x12), so the lack of a 2x12 chain isn't an indication of compatibility.

Comment: Just adding a comment in reference to @Batman 's earlier discussion. SRAM released 12-speed Red and Force groups, and these have an option to go either 1x or doubles. If you look at their current page of chains, you'll see an 11-speed and 12-speed Red chain. There are no chains specific for 1x or double cranksets. https://www.sram.com/en/sram/road/products/chains?filters=&sort=Relevancy&page=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 1x specific chain is designed with 2 different width specifications.

On a standard chain, only the spacing between the inside plates matters.

The 1x specific chains are made to fit a narrow/wide chainring, which means that the spacing between both inside plates and outer plates must be within tolerance.

[image]

It only matters if you are running a 1x specific drive train.

Comment: Interesting, I assume the reason for this is to decrease throwing the chain from the chainring?

Comment: Yes, it's to prevent the chain from falling off.

Comment: Have they actually made a new chain, or have marketing just taken a normal chain, added a second width specification to the packaging label and $20 to the cost?

Comment: No one can answer that for certain. However, I know from personal experience that a standard chain doesn't work well with XX1.

Comment: @mattnz I can respect the increased tolerances.  I can't respect the marketing.

Comment: At this point, the marketing is irrelevant. If the chain is required for the drive train to work well, it is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

**General Note:** Chains should match the speed they are manufactured for, in order to work correctly (ie, 11sp drivetrains require 11sp chains, etc). This is due to the different spacings on the cassette from one size to another: 11sp cassettes have narrower sprocket spacing than 10sp cassettes, so 11sp drivetrains require narrower chains as a result.

**Specific to SRAM:**

**SRAM MTB:** According to SRAM's [compatibility chart](https://sram-cdn-pull-zone-gsdesign.netdna-ssl.com/cdn/farfuture/sTuwP23_VJzJytn50DxOK5EgP33HK-ODDtsZRDGHK9Y/mtime:1430932938/sites/default/files/techdocs/gen_0000000004917_rev_c_compatibility_map_2016_mtb_components.pdf), the XX1 chains are only compatible with 1x drivetrains. However, a similar note is not present for the X1 chains, so presumably those can be used with both 1x and 2x drivetrains and by that same logic, the PC 1130 chain should also be compatible with 1x11 drivetrains.

**SRAM Road:** No, there doesn't appear to be any difference in chain compatibility between 1x and 2x drivetrains. Note that both the [Force 22](https://www.sram.com/sram/road/family/sram-force) and [Force 1](https://www.sram.com/sram/road/family/sram-force-1) product pages feature the same chain.